# Pairing names in Python if condition is met

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm in charge of creating a quick program that will put people in pairs for a sports competition I am helping to host. I need to make sure that 2 specific names will not be paired together.

I have been able to create something that will take a list of names, shuffle them and then generate another txt file with the pairings.

This works really well, however part of the requirement is to prevent two names being paired together. I haven't used Python for quite a while and forgot if it is possible.

```
from random import shuffle

with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
    names = [name.strip() for name in f]

shuffle(names)

pairs = zip(names[::2], names[1::2])

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Doubles Pairings 2019 are: \n \n')
    for pair in pairs:
        f.write('%s is paired with %s\n' % pair)
```

The expected results are as follows:

```
Doubles pairings 2019 are: 

Amy is paired with Jenny
Emily is paired with Lydia
Andrew is paired with Peter
Patrick is paired with Louise
Donald is paired with Sean
Sarah is paired with George
Jade is paired with Julia
Katie is paired with Joe
```

The results are obviously random but it would be great to ensure that Amy can never be paired with Sean for example.

Comment: One option is to include a check, `if ('Amy','Sean') in pairs:` and have it re-shuffle, at the basic level

Comment: @G.Anderson ah, thank you so much!! Basic level does the job perfectly - cheers.

Comment: Since it suffices for your problem, I added it as an answer. Feel free to accept it, or wait for a better answer to come along!

Comment: Best thing, for your program + for this question, is to separate IO from logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to include a check, `if ('Amy','Sean') in pairs:` and have it re-shuffle, as the basic method

Per suggestion, don't forget to check which direction the names are being paired, i.e. if each name is from list one or list two it could be

`('Amy','Sean')` or `('Sean','Amy')`

Answer (score 0):

You could arrange your list so that both names which should not be paired are in one half and shuffle only the rest:

```
from random import shuffle

no_pair = ['Amy', 'Sean']
for n in no_pair:
    names.remove(n)
shuffle(names)
names = no_pair + names
```

Then simply pair by cut the list in two halves:

```
N = len(names)//2
lhs = names[:N]
rhs = names[N:]

#print(*zip(lhs, rhs), sep='\n')

#('Amy', 'Andrew')
#('Sean', 'Jade')                                            
#('Donald', 'Joe')                                           
#('Emily', 'George')                                         
#('Jenny', 'Peter')                                          
#('Julia', 'Patrick')                                        
#('Louise', 'Lydia')                                         
#('Katie', 'Sarah')
```